# aspx page inside colorbox popup not firing serverside code

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, colorbox

I have the following situation:

An aspx page (index.aspx) that open another aspx (popups/signin.aspx) page in colorbox popup, when the signin.aspx open, i have a username & password textboxes and an asp button, once I click the asp button the page redirects popups/signin.aspx and don't even go the click event code of the button.

I also have an update panel in the signin.aspx but both the button and the update panel are not working.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Without code how can we imagine what you are making mistake.....

Comment: in the server side code, I am checking the username and password to redirect the user to the index.aspx page or showing him an error in the popup inside the update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this problem by using the html page with jquery request to an aspx page and inside the jquery ajax function I am reloading the parent page.